# Checkout Programatically

Tags: payment

i'm looking for a way to create an order pragmatically and on complete  redirect to the payment method url. any help would be appreciated.

I have created an observer that changes the fixed price to price+fee the custom form that creates a user adds addresses and logs in. but i need to be able to go to the payment gateway url.

Comment: Try to download any quick order extension from connect and look through it

Comment: good shout but they all seem to be ioncubed.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=quick+order&t=1&p=1 these are free

Comment: thanks but these dont include checkout . they just do what ive already got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i was initially looking for a way to avoid using the one page checkout in magento and not have any real checkout form just a button to autorize.

Ok so this was allot more complex than i first imagined, the first step was to create a customer programatically with an address this is quite well documented on how to do this. The hard part was to invoke onepage checkout without the form.

```
/*Get the Initial Store ID*/
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

/* Get one page checkouts singleton model */
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');

/* Initialize the checkout this gets the current quote along with the associated  session and addresses */
$checkout->initCheckout();

/* Set the quote to the current store */
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

/* As the session is created tell onepage to use the register method not guest */ 
$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');

/* Set the shipping method you can use flatrate_flatrate aswell */
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');

/* Save the payment method paypal_express, banktransfer, chekmo etc */
$order = $checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'paypal_express'));

/** Try catch arround the save order method that does all the save and checks if the gateway needs to redirect.

try {
     $checkout->saveOrder();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    /* If it fails then log the exception and sendpayment failed email. */
    Mage::logException($ex);
    Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($checkout->getQuote(), $ex->getMessage());

}

/* Get the redirect method and redirect from the controller */
$this->_redirectUrl($checkout->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl());
```

I hope the above solution helps someone else. this is working in magento 1.9.1